# Can't get jqgrid addRowData to work

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

First off, I want to make it clear that I know there are other posts quite similar to mine in these forums. Unfortunately, using them I have failed to get addRowData to work.  I have a table that is defined like this:

```
var tableDef = {
        scroll: 1,
        url:"/SCSalesDataReport/showReport/getSalesReportJSON",
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:['id','Type', 'Name', 'Total','In','Out'],
        colModel:[
            { name: 'id', index: 'testid', hidden: true},     
            {name:'type',index:'type', width:10, sortable:true},
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:40, sortable:true},
            {name:'total',index:'total', width: 10, sortable:false},
            {name:'in',index:'in', width:10, sortable:true},
            {name:'out',index:'out', width:10, sortable:true}, ],
        rowNum:100,
        mtype: "GET",
        sortname: 'id',  
        viewrecords: true,
        height : '500',
        altRows: true,
        autowidth: true,
};
```

and for what it is worth, that is working and populating the table as one would expect.  Unfortunately, using some of the posts I've seen in these forums, I can't add data to the table once it has been created.  I'm trying to add a row via a link, like this:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var a = document.getElementById("addRow");
    a.onclick = function() {
        var count = $("#grid").getGridParam("reccount");
        var newRowData = {'id':count, 'Type':"ADDEDTYPE", 'Name':"Insert 1", 'Total':"10",'In':"50",'Out':"40"}; 
        jQuery("#myTable").addRowData("id", newRowData);
        jQuery("#myTable").trigger("reloadGrid");

      return false;
    }
 }
```

which is connected to this tag:

```
<a id="addRow" href="www.google.com">Oh please, for the love of all that is holy... add a row!</a>
```

If someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, that would be *greatly* appreciated.  I strongly suspect I'm just doing something dumb, or overlooking something simple.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want the reloadGrid in there. I don't use it and my newRowData calls work fine. Also, you're missing the **position** property in your call to addRowData (not sure if it's required, but it can't hurt).

Also, I think your hash keys in newRowData need to match case with the colModel. You've got keys 'Type','Name', etc in newRowData, but in your colModel they're called 'type','name', etc.

see the definition for addRowData at http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods